# System Memory on Android

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean

This is my first time here. I wanted to ask if 4.96gb of system memory is normal. My phone is Samsung Galaxy s3 that is 16gb and system memory is the top consumer of my memory. It wasn't like this before. It takes alot of space in my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. As you may know, qll device with storage do not give yoy wccess to all 100% of it. For example, a Samsung galaxy tab 2 uses 3.41gb as system. So, as devices get newer, more stuff (apps and features) are added, meaning more used. So, long story short, yes it is normal. Enjoy your device :)